# SwiftUI: how can I hide scroll indicators?

Tags: swiftui

I have a very simple List view in a SwiftUI view.

```
List {
    ForEach(model.items, id: \.self) { item in
        Section(header: item.sv) {
          .....
        }
    }
}
```

I just want to hide the scroll indicators (in my case I want to hide the vertical scroll indicator to the right).

Is it possible to hide the scroll indicators on a List view?

Comment: Seems like I should switch to LazyVGrid looking at that post. I'll check it out and see.

Comment: that does work. thanks.

Comment: In that case, you can close this as a duplicate